# Faster way to update cells

Tags: jquery, datatables

I can get the data() object on the table and do statements like

```
 data[x][y] = 123;
```

but it doesn't actually update the table. Using the `table.cell(row, col).data(123)` method of updating cells is insanely slower when trying to update a thousand records.

Is there a faster way to update cells than using `table.cell(row, col).data(123)`?

Comment: No. You must use the given functions to update the table.

Comment: Hmm... I just need to update the values in a single column to all be the same number on about 600 rows. And that column isn't even visible so the display doesn't even have to change. 6+ seconds seems like a ridiculous amount of time to accomplish that. That's over a second per 100 rows.

Comment: The datatables plugin is really slow when dealing with many rows.

Comment: Hence my post, lol. Actually it does sorting and filtering pretty fast. Just updating seems to be super slow.

Comment: The column I'm trying to update is actually hidden and never displays to the user... was hoping there might be a way to update the data directly since it doesn't have to update the screen.